# Можно ли в MySQL хранить объекты TObject или ссылки на них, созданные в Delphi приложении?

Tags: mysql, delphi

Если да, то как сохранить объект, что бы он оставался после перезапуска приложения, как будет выглядеть SQL запрос или как получить ссылку объекта, сохранить в базу, что бы в дальнейшем прочесть ее и обратиться к объекту, без перезапуска приложения?

UPD

Я сейчас храню список объектов так, `PlayerList: TDictionary<String, TPlayer>;`
 и обращаюсь к списку через критическую секцию, если я смогу хранить в базе [имя]  [ссылка] и при обращении клиента(Player) брать ссылку для его объекта мне это облегчит жизнь, и хотелось бы узнать можно ли сохранить сам объект так что бы после перезапуска приложения он был в том же состоянии.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @Kromster честно говоря не знаю что еще дописать к вопросу...

Comment: Приведите пример. Какие объекты или ссылки вы хотите хранить в СУБД и что при этом вызывает у вас сложности. Что требуется получить и для каких целей. К примеру в таблице в СУБД вы можете хранить названия форм и объектов.

Comment: @Deft добавил в вопроссе

Comment: Сериализуйте объект (например, в стринг) - тогда его можно без проблем сохранить в поле БД. Ну и соответственно при извлечении - десериализовать.

Comment: @Akina так? { var

Input, Output : TStringStream;
S : string;

begin
...

Input.WriteComponent(Form1);
Input.Seek(0,0);
ObjectBinaryToText(Input, Output);
Memo1.Lines.Add(Output.DataString);

...
end;}

Comment: Посмотрел я тут, что о сериализации объектов в Delphi думают поисковики. Оказалось, что по их мнению разумнее сериализовать в XML. Даже вполне себе готовые коды имеются (вот пример: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/delphi/stat/XML-Serialize-Delphi.php). Так что полагаю, есть смысл поискать готовое и максимально подходящее Вам решение, а не изобретать что-то своё.

Comment: Вам необходимо создать в базе сущности соответствующие вашим объектным моделям, и при запуске загружать состояние сущности и все подвязаные данные!

Comment: @JVic спасибо, учту.

Comment: @Akina спасибо за "Сериализуйте" и " в XML" , теперь знаю о чем читать. Если не затруднит, как ссылку на объект получить в строковом виде? Так можно? IntToStr(@Player)

Comment: @ArtGrek13, зачем вам такая ссылка? Сохранять ее в БД смысла никакого нет, поскольку ссылка на объект - это всего лишь указатель на область памяти, где хранятся все поля /переменные этого объекта. В данном процессе. Будет другой процесс (например - перезапустили программу или запустили еще одну) - для него ссылка будет невалидной. Вам нужно сохранять именно содержимое объекта, его поля/переменные. А при необходимости загрузки - создавать новый объект и загружать в его поля сохраненное содержимое. Это и есть [де]сериализация.

Comment: Тем более, что `Player` это уже указатель на объект. И в случае `@Player` вы получите "указатель на указатель"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Хранить объекты – можно.**
Для этого объект сериализуется (записывается состояние всех его полей), например в строку или бинарный поток. Для загрузки делается десериализация - создание объекта с заполнением всех полей из строки/потока/итп.

**Хранить ссылки на объекты – "нельзя".**
Так как каждый объект каждый раз создается в произвольном/непредсказуемом месте в памяти, сохранять на него указатель – бессмысленно.

**Пересоздавать ссылки между объектами – можно**
Чтобы пересоздать ссылку между объектами обычно достаточно сохранить какую-либо уникальную метку объекта (id, GUID), а потом при десериализации её прочитать и по ней найти этот объект и взять на него ссылку. Пересоздание ссылок стоит делать после пересоздания ВСЕХ объектов, чтобы не было проблем с цикличностью и порядком следования объектов.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем объект при http подключении клиента в **AContext.Data**

Сохраняем в базу пару SessionId, адрес объекта `IntToStr(Integer(AContext.Data)`

При разрыве соединения в **OnDisconnect** пишем `AContext.Data := nil`

Объект не уничтожен и адрес на него хранится в базе

При повторном соединение находим адрес по сессии и присваиваем `AContext.Data := Pointer(StrToInt(строка с адресом к объекту))`

При уничтожении объекта в базу пишем **nil**